# Are there unsolved problems known to be not independent of the axiomatic system it is proposed in?

Tags: big-list, axioms

> Are there unsolved problems known to be not independent of the axiomatic system it is proposed in?

For example, is Goldbach's conjecture known to be provable using the axioms of PA?

I believe I have heard something like this, but I can't find it anywhere on the internet.

If there is such problem, can you give a reference to the proof that it is not independent? (If it is not very long, you can also place it as an answer of course)

---

**Note:** It is also fine if it is a problem that has been solved, as long as the proof that the problem isn't independent doesn't use the fact that is has been proven. I'm just interested in how such proofs look.

Thank you in advance.

---

I already have the category where solving the problem is reduced to a finite, though too long, computation, thanks to user41404. Are there other problems known?

Comment: There is a counterexample to Goldbach between 10^999 and 10^9999, but youre probably looking for famous ones.  Btw, Goldbach is not known to be decidable in PA.

Comment: @user41404 I'd be interested in anything, because I have never seen such proof. Actually if it was a solved problem but the proof doesn't use the fact that is has been proved, it'd be okay to, I will add that to the question.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112097/important-open-problems-that-have-already-been-reduced-to-a-finite-but-infeasibl/112342#112342

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed related.

Comment: All such problems are reducible to a finite computation, just order all proofs by length say and search

Comment: @user41404 Do you mean all the problems in the link, or all unsolved problems known to be dependent?

Comment: the latter _____

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a counterexample to Goldbach somewhere between $10^{99999}$ and $10^{999999}$.
There is an odd number of twin primes in the same interval.
To prove or disprove just check all cases.

Comment: Didn't think about that, thank you. Also, wouldn't this imply that if Goldbach is false, that it then provably false is in PA? (+1)

Comment: Right, cause we just check 2,4,6... until we find it